# How to run PHP script with submit function of ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, jquery

I wrote this JavaScript code for login system. I have a problem connecting it to PHP file. I want to display a message from my PHP script and hide this form.

```
    $('#submit').click(function()
    {
var email=$("#email").val();

var password=$("#password").val();
if(ck_email.test(email) && ck_password.test(password) )
{
$("#form").show().html("<h1>Thank you!</h1>");
}
return false;
});
```

**PHP Script**

```
include ('database_connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
if (empty($error)) //send to Database if there's no error '

    { // If everything's OK...

       // Make sure the email address is available:
       $query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM members  WHERE Email ='$Email'";
       $result_verify_email = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_verify_email);
       if (!$result_verify_email) {            echo ' Database Error Occured ';
       }

       if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_email) == 0) { // IF no previous user is using this email .


        // Create a unique  activation code:
        $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));


        $query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO `members` ( `Username`, `Email`, `Password`, `College`, `Activation`) VALUES ( '$name', '$Email', '$Password', '$College' '$activation')";


        $result_insert_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_insert_user);
        if (!$result_insert_user) {
        echo 'Query Failed ';
         }

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { //If the Insert Query was successfull.


        // Send the email:
        $message = " To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
        $message .= WEBSITE_URL . '/activate.php?email=' . urlencode($Email) . "&key=$activation";
        mail($Email, 'Registration Confirmation', $message, 'From: cr@gmail.com');

        // Flush the buffered output.


        // Finish the page:
        echo '<div class="success">Thank you for
registering! A confirmation email
has been sent to '.$Email.' Please click on the Activation Link to Activate your account </div>';


         } else { // If it did not run OK.
         echo '<div class="errormsgbox">You could not be registered due to a system
error. We apologize for any
inconvenience.</div>';
         }

        } else { // The email address is not available.
        echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >That email
address has already been registered.
</div>';
        }
    } else {//If the "error" array contains error msg , display them
echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
        foreach ($error as $key => $values) {

            echo '  <li>'.$values.'</li>';

}
echo '</ol></div>';
}
  mysqli_close($dbc);//Close the DB Connection
}
```

I know that I have to use Ajax, but, I am unable to get the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send a post or get request to your webserver-adress on which your php-script runs. The answer you get ist the echo-part of your PHP-Script.

For example-usage with JQuery and post:

```
    $.post(server+'index.php',{ email: $("#email").val(),formsubmitted:true, password: $("#password").val() }, function(data) {
        $("#form").show().html(data);
        });
```

In the first post-Parameter you say where your server ist, and what php-file you want to access. Usually it is

```
   server = "http://127.0.0.1/"
```

as localhost for server. In the second parameter you give the PHP-Script the Post-Variables, which PHP can use in $POST['email'] for example to work with. And the third-Parameter is the Callback, which will be executed, when an answer from the server arrives.

Of course you still have to edit some of your PHP posted above to make it work. For example load the $Email-Variable from the Post fields before you use it:

```
    $Email = $POST['email'];
```

Comment: I want to display something like 'Login successful'. But your code seems to display the email and password?

Comment: If you want to display 'Login successful' clientside (in your Javascript) you will have to echo this in your PHP-File. Where do you host your PHP? On a local XAMPP? Perhaps it is the best to check, if you can get and display any response from the server.